# What happens when an activity closes before it's result activity?

Tags: android

I'm playing around with the voice recognition API and wanted to know what I should do if the activity that started it gets closed before the Google Voice Recognition activity is done receiving a result from the user. In other words, is there a way to force close the voice recognition activity which was started by calling `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: You are not so clear. Please be more precise and maybe give some code.

Comment: I don't know how much more precise I can be. Let me try to reexplain my question. Say you have the Google Voice Recognition dialog open, waiting or processing a user's voice input, but then the activity that started this voice recognition activity gets closed. How can forcefully close the voice recognition activity because they original activity that is suppose to receive the result is no longer open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, all I had to do was do finishActivity(requestCode).